# lua corona widget.newScrollView verticalScrollDisabled doesn't work

Tags: lua, scrollview, coronasdk

I have created a ScrollView with this code:

```
local function BuildScrollView( )
    scrollView = widget.newScrollView(
    {
        top = 0,
        left = 0,
        width = display.actualContentWidth,
        height = display.actualContentHeight,
        scrollWidth = 0,
        scrollHeight = 0,
        backgroundColor = { 0, 0, 0, 0.5},
        verticalScrollDisabled=true;
    }) 
end
```

this works fine :)

then upon a click I use this:

```
scrollView:setIsLocked( true )
```

Then later I want to unlock the ScrollView with this code:

```
function ResetPlanetTaps()
    scrollView.verticalScrollDisabled=true;
    scrollView:setIsLocked( false );
end
```

But the ScrollView still scrolls vertically.
How do i stop the vertical scrolling?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you should specify as a second parameter what axis you want to lock:

```
scrollView:setIsLocked(true, "vertical")
```

The second parameter, *axis*, as stated from the docs:

> Directional axis upon which to lock or unlock the scroll view, either "horizontal" or "vertical".

You can see scrollView `setIsLocked` [documentation here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ScrollViewWidget/setIsLocked.html), and the open source code and relevant line [here on github](https://github.com/coronalabs/framework-widget/blob/master/widgetLibrary/widget_scrollview.lua#L623).

Comment: Many thanks Basilio :)
I used "horizontal" and it worked fine.